# How to call method in child xaml from parent in Xamarin Forms ?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to perform inheritance of one xaml in another, and trigger call from child.
Child xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="project.NavigationBar">
        <ContentView.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout 
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Button
                            x:Name="NavigationBarButton" 
                            Clicked="NavigationBarButton_Clicked" 
                            Text="Gallery">
                        </Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

Child xaml.cs:

```
        private void NavigationBarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Parent xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="project.main"
             xmlns:views="project.NavigationBar"
            >
    <StackLayout>
                <views:NavigationBar/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Parent xaml.cs:

```
    private void NavigationBarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Get call from child there and do my logic
    }
```

How could i trigger click call in child and throws it in parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a EventHandler in your CustomView:

```
public event EventHandler myClickEvent;
```

Then, in add the function that will be called (still in your customView:

```
void myClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

In your Page, bind the Method, to your view, that will be called:

```
  <views:NavigationBar myClickEvent="MyClickEvent"/>
```

In your page.xaml.cs:

```
void MyClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //handle method here
    }
```

Comment: great, it works.
if i need to call another events in tab, i need to throw them like this:
  <views:NavigationBar myClickEvent="MyClickEvent myClickEvent2="MyClickEvent2 myClickEvent3="MyClickEvent3"/>
?

Comment: On more question:
how to send response back from parent to child xaml and do some stuff in child logic ?